# String split by pipe and put in columns

Tags: r

I have this vector of strings. I would like to split them by `|` and extract fields 2,3,4 and 10 into four different columns. I could split the first string (test [1] ) with `unlist(strsplit(test,split='|',fixed=TRUE))[c(2:4,10)]`  but I am not sure how to do for all strings in the vector. Any help would be appreciated.

```
test <- c("PR;ANN=T|splice_region_variant&intron_variant|LOW|PER3|ENSG00000049246|transcript|ENST00000377532|protein_coding|13/20|c.1658+7G>T||||||,T|splice_region_variant&intron_variant|LOW|PER3|ENSG00000049246|transcript|ENST00000613533|protein_coding|14/21|c.1658+7G>T||||||,T|splice_region_variant&intron_variant|LOW|PER3|ENSG00000049246|transcript|ENST00000614998|protein_coding|14/22|c.1658+7G>T||||||,T|splice_region_variant&intron_variant|LOW|PER3|ENSG00000049246|transcript|ENST00000361923|protein_coding|13/20|c.1634+7G>T||||||,T|intron_variant|MODIFIER|RP3-467L1.4|ENSG00000236266|transcript|ENST00000451646|antisense|1/2|n.239+7677C>A||||||;AC=64;AC_AFR=1;AC_AMR=0;AC_Adj=64;AC_EAS=0;AC_FIN=0;AC_Het=64;AC_Hom=0;AC_NFE=63;AC_OTH=0;AC_SAS=0;AF=5.271e-04;AN=121410;AN_AFR=10404;AN_AMR=11578;AN_Adj=121084;AN_EAS=8652;AN_FIN=6614;AN_NFE=66616;AN_OTH=906;AN_SAS=16314;CSQ=A|ENSG00000236266|ENST00000451646|Transcript|intron_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant||||||rs200733001|2||-1|RP3-467L1.4|Clo... <truncated>
"PR;ANN=G|intron_variant|MODIFIER|PIGK|ENSG00000142892|transcript|ENST00000370812|protein_coding|10/10|c.1072-59T>C||||||,G|intron_variant|MODIFIER|PIGK|ENSG00000142892|transcript|ENST00000445065|protein_coding|7/7|c.790-59T>C||||||,G|intron_variant|MODIFIER|PIGK|ENSG00000142892|transcript|ENST00000487906|nonsense_mediated_decay|6/6|n.*561-59T>C||||||"
)
```

Comment: can you check your data, it is giving error

Comment: The data has a syntax error so I can't easily determine what you have but maybe: `read.table(text = test, sep = "|")[c(2:4, 10)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are more than one element, loop over the `list` created with `strsplit`, extract (`[`), the elements, and `rbind` those to a `matrix`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(test,split='|',fixed=TRUE), 
    `[`, c(2:4, 10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `lapply` expression:

```
lapply(strsplit(test, '\\|'), function(x) x[c(2:4,10)])
[[1]]
[1] "splice_region_variant&intron_variant" "LOW"                                 
[3] "PER3"                                 "c.1658+7G>T"                         

[[2]]
[1] "intron_variant" "MODIFIER"       "PIGK"           "c.1072-59T>C"
```

Alternatively, use `sapply`:

```
sapply(strsplit(test, '\\|'), function(x) x[c(2:4,10)])
     [,1]                                   [,2]            
[1,] "splice_region_variant&intron_variant" "intron_variant"
[2,] "LOW"                                  "MODIFIER"      
[3,] "PER3"                                 "PIGK"          
[4,] "c.1658+7G>T"                          "c.1072-59T>C"
```

Data:

```
test <- c("PR;ANN=T|splice_region_variant&intron_variant|LOW|PER3|ENSG00000049246|transcript|ENST00000377532|protein_coding|13/20|c.1658+7G>T||||||,T|splice_region_variant&intron_variant|LOW|PER3|ENSG00000049246|transcript|ENST00000613533|protein_coding|14/21|c.1658+7G>T||||||,T|splice_region_variant&intron_variant|LOW|PER3|ENSG00000049246|transcript|ENST00000614998|protein_coding|14/22|c.1658+7G>T||||||,T|splice_region_variant&intron_variant|LOW|PER3|ENSG00000049246|transcript|ENST00000361923|protein_coding|13/20|c.1634+7G>T||||||,T|intron_variant|MODIFIER|RP3-467L1.4|ENSG00000236266|transcript|ENST00000451646|antisense|1/2|n.239+7677C>A||||||;AC=64;AC_AFR=1;AC_AMR=0;AC_Adj=64;AC_EAS=0;AC_FIN=0;AC_Het=64;AC_Hom=0;AC_NFE=63;AC_OTH=0;AC_SAS=0;AF=5.271e-04;AN=121410;AN_AFR=10404;AN_AMR=11578;AN_Adj=121084;AN_EAS=8652;AN_FIN=6614;AN_NFE=66616;AN_OTH=906;AN_SAS=16314;CSQ=A|ENSG00000236266|ENST00000451646|Transcript|intron_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant||||||rs200733001|2||-1|RP3-467L1.4|Clo... <truncated>",
"PR;ANN=G|intron_variant|MODIFIER|PIGK|ENSG00000142892|transcript|ENST00000370812|protein_coding|10/10|c.1072-59T>C||||||,G|intron_variant|MODIFIER|PIGK|ENSG00000142892|transcript|ENST00000445065|protein_coding|7/7|c.790-59T>C||||||,G|intron_variant|MODIFIER|PIGK|ENSG00000142892|transcript|ENST00000487906|nonsense_mediated_decay|6/6|n.*561-59T>C||||||")
```